# Mistake in Apostol's Calculus Volume II regarding inner products?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inner-products

It looks like there is a completely miswritten formula in Apostol's Calculus, Volume II, regarding inner products. The formula states that: 
"If $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ are any two vectors in $V_2$, define $(x,y)$ by the formula $(x,y)=2x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2$. Through online research and consulting with a friend, it looks like $(x,y)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$ is in fact the correct formula for inner products, but I wanted to make sure the book's version was not also correct, because this is more than a minute typo. Is there any validity to the book's definition?

Comment: Isn't it explained somewhere in the surrounding text that this is a non-canonical example? (I don't have the book here to check.)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021260/norm-and-inner-product/2021288#2021288

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no typos. One can define different inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ than the standard one. See for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507737/9464) question.

If you read carefully what the book by Apostol (page 14 and page 15) says, you would find that he gives you both the standard and non-standard examples:

> [image]

Here is the definition in his book:
[image]

Comment: Okay, I reread the statement that the inner product is defined axiomatically rather than by a specific formula, and this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The *canonical* inner product in $\mathbb R^2$ is given by your formula, i.e.

$$\langle x,y\rangle = x_1y_1+x_2y_2$$

However, there are *many other* possible inner products in $\mathbb R^2$. Apostol is giving an example of a second choice of inner product in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

One should check that the proposed formula actually defines a (real) [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

**Symmetry**

Does $(x,y) = (y,x)$ ?  Yes, it is easily checked that exchanging roles of $x,y$ does not change the result defined by $(x,y)=2x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2$.

**Linearity in each argument**

Given symmetry, it suffices to check linearity in just one argument:

$$ (au+bv,y) = a(u,y) + b(v,y) $$

Because the formula is homogeneous of degree $1$ in the components of each argument, this check is straightforward.

**Positive-definiteness**

Usually the most interesting property to check, as is the case here.  We want to show:

$$ (x,x) \ge 0 \text{ with equality only when } x=0 $$

Note that by the formula $(x,x) = 2x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2$.  It suffices to show that this expression is nonnegative and only zero when $x_1 = x_2 = 0$.

To see this easily, rewrite the expression:

$$ 2x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = x_1^2 + (x_1 + x_2)^2 $$

From this clearly we get a nonnegative result, and we only get zero if both $x_1=0$ and $x_1+x_2 = 0$, implying that $x_1=x_2=0$.